# Get asp radio button value thru javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I googled and search all over to get the value of asp radiobutton value thru javascript but I keep getting undefined. I looked for almost every way to get the rb value but sure why I get undefined. Any help is appreciated.

The clientfunction() is called when clicking on the dialog window OK button.

Here is my code.

```
    <div style="width: 480px;">
<MyUserControl:FormItem ID="FormItem1" runat="server" Label="Outcome" IsRequired="true">
                            <Content>
                                <div>
                                    <asp:RadioButton ID="rbThisButton" GroupName="outcome" Text="This radio button" runat="server" Checked="<%# model.thisbutton %>" />
                                </div>

                            </Content>
                        </MyUserControl:FormItem>








 <script type="text/javascript">
     function clientFunction() {

         debugger;
         $('select[id$=rbThisButton]').each(function () {
             var val = this.value;
             if (val == 'All') { flag = true; }
         });

         var test = $('#<%=rbThisButton.ClientID %> input[type=radio]:checked').val();

         var selectedVal = $("[id$='rbThisButton']").find(":checked").val();


         var selectedvalue = $('#<%= rbThisButton.ClientID %> input:checked').val()


         debugger;
         var rates = document.getElementById('rbThisButton'); 

     }   
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: When is `clientFunction` being invoked?

Comment: ClientFunction is invoked when clicking on the 'OK' button.

Comment: An `asp:radiobutton` produces an `<input type=radio>`, so why are you trying a selector of: `select[id$=rbThisButton]` instead of `input[type=radio][id*=rbThisButton]`

Comment: You don't need to check for `:checked` since all the radio buttons in that group will/should have the same name. You just need to as for the value of the radio button with the `name` of whatever you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if the radio button is checked, you can simply do the following:

```
var isChecked = $('#<%=rbThisButton.ClientID %>').is(":checked");
```

---

To break down why your attempts were not working:

```
$('select[id$=rbThisButton]')
//This is looking for a SELECT (DropDownList), not an input

$('#<%=rbThisButton.ClientID %> input[type=radio]:checked')
$("[id$='rbThisButton']").find(":checked")
$('#<%= rbThisButton.ClientID %> input:checked')
//Both a space in a selector and the .find() function are looking for CHILDREN
//so you're not finding anything with these - your radio button has no children
```